# How can I keep track of which link the user clicked on using sessions?

Tags: php, html

I'm a student so apologies in advance for the beginner question.

Basically I'm populating a table full of items from a database, and when the user clicks on the 'Title' attribute for any given item, I want it to take them to a page where they can edit the details of that particular item.

Through the research I've already done, I think I would need to store the title in the session array, and then use the title to query the database to display the attributes of the item on the new page, allowing my user to edit it. But I'm just not sure how I would go about this.

If it helps, here's what I'm currently using to populate the table:

```
while($rowObj = $queryResult->fetch_object()){ //creates rest of table
            echo "<div class = 'class'>
            <span class = A> {$rowObj->A}</span>
            <span class = title><a href=edit.php>{$rowObj->title}</a></span>
            <span class = B>{$rowObj->B}</span>
            <span class = C>{$rowObj->C}</span>
            <span class = D>{$rowObj->D}</span>
            </div>";
         }
```

I know it has something to do with the link I'm displaying as well. I'm just really not sure how to proceed.
I appreciate the help in advance (:

Comment: No, this should not use sessions to begin with - you should pass the title (better would be an actual _id_, that identifies the record) as a GET parameter in the link to the edit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an edit.php file

So you can simply do

```
<a href="edit.php?title=${title}">Example</a>
```

In your case something like this

```
<span class = title><a href="edit.php?title=$rowObj->title">{$rowObj->title}</a></span>
```

Then on your edit.php you can use

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
// Do what ever you want to do here.
```

It is worth noting that you should use an ID instead of the title as you could have duplicates or the url may break.

This has nothing to do with sessions and you should avoid over use of sessions

Answer (score 0):

Its better to search by a primary key in database like id which is unique. Because titles may be repetitive and searching by title may have more than one results.

You can send id to the second page by the get method:

`<a href=".../edit.php?id=<?php echo $result->id();?>">`

Its better not to use session but if you do not want ids to be seen in the url you can use sessions to access the id in the second page.